# React : Looking for a drawer solution

Tags: reactjs, draw

I'm working in a react project and I want to have a drawer that I can create some forms : Triangle, rectangle, lines etc..
Habe you any ideas/package that I should use ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many options like you can use ui libraries like [mui](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/), [mantine](https://mantine.dev/core/drawer/) etc. Or you can also use npm packages like [react-modern-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modern-drawer), [rc-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-drawer) etc.
Then, inside the drawer you can put your form etc.